# How call a maven plugin explicitly and non running otherwise?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin

Eventually I generate some Java code with explicite `mvn generate-sources` which calls CXF plugin defined in `pom.xml`.

**Q:** How to configure plugin to make it running when I call it explicitly and not running otherwise?

If I set `phase` to `generate-sources`, then `mvn generate-sources` works, but `mvn compile` also triggers it (that's unwanted).

If I set `phase` to `none`, then `mvn generate-sources` does nothing (unwanted), but `mvn compile` does not trigger it (ok).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <!--<phase>none</phase>-->
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This is weird. To `compile` your code, you **must** generate the sources first.

Comment: What is the problem if the code is regenerated at `mvn compile`? Usually generated code is needed for the full build process and then it is useful that `generate-sources` is called.

Comment: If you want to run the plugin outside the build lifecycle you can try: 1. set phase to none; 2. `mvn cxf-codegen-plugin:<the-goal-name>`

Comment: Tried `mvn org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:wsdl2java` - "Nothing to generate" I've been told.

Comment: @PavelVlasov this is probably because your configuration is within an execution and not taken as a generic configuration for a command line execution. By the way, which version of Maven are you using?

Answer (score 18):

You can run any plugin from command line and as such exclusively it (and not part of a Maven phase, in this case), simply configuring the plugin in your POM (plugins section) with a generic configuration (not nested within any execution sub-section).

As such, the given configuration will be used for any execution. Since the concerned plugin does not have any default [binding](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) through any Maven [packaging](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html) (which instead happens for other plugins, i.e. Maven Compiler or Surefire plugins), then the configuration will be picked up only by your command line execution.

```
mvn org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:wsdl2java
```

Would then run the plugin you configured with the required configuration, given in your POM:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <configuration><!-- HERE YOUR CONFIG --></configuration>
</plugin>
```

As you can see, there is no execution (and hence no phase) described for the plugin, but a global configuration is supplied. As global, it will be used by your command line execution as well.

This approach is slightly different than what you tried:

```
mvn generate-sources
```

When executing `generate-sources`, you are executing a phase and as such any other [preceding phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). However, the preceding phases do not affect your project and as such you would get the same behavior, plus the side effect of also having it as part of the `compile` phase.

---

If you really want to have it as part of the `generate-sources` phase (for whatever reason) and keep on running `mvn generate-sources` without the side effect described above, then you can wrap it in a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), adding to your POM:

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>generate-cxf</id>
      <build>
         <defaultGoal>generate-sources</defaultGoal>
         <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions><!-- HERE YOUR EXECUTIONS--></executions>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
      </build>
     </profile>
</profiles>
```

You could then execute:

```
mvn generate-sources -Pgenerate-cxf
```

And it will activate the profile above and as such your plugin and executions but not impacting (side effects) any other phase or the default build.

Moreover, via the `defaultGoal` [element](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element) configuration, you can even simply invoke:

```
mvn -Pgenerate-cxf
```

And you will have exactly the same behavior (although a bit cryptic I would say).

---

Last but not least, since [Maven **3.3.1**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5768), you can invoke just a simple plugin execution (keeping your binding to the `none` phase this time) from command line (specifying the desired execution id) as following:

```
    mvn org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:VERSION_HERE:wsdl2java:@EXEC_ID_HERE
```

The command above will only (and only) execute your target execution.

Comment: @PavelVlasov did this help?